# Oracle DB: Can one db file be shared between table space

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Can one db file be shared between table space ?

I am deleting temp table space as below,

> 1)Get all the files in  table
>   space :: SELECT FILE_NAME  FROM DBA_TEMP_FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME =
>   'TEMPRM_TEMP';
>
> 2)Drop all the files in the table space :: ALTER 
>   TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP DROP TEMPFILE
>   '/tmp/TEMPRM/create/TEMPRM/datafile/o1_mf_temprm_t_bw3yo9lv_.tmp';
>
> 3)Drop the actual table space :: DROP TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP INCLUDING
>   CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;

Are there any harm with this procedure ?

Answer (score 2):

is this the only temp tablespace in your database? if the answer is yes,  then you will not be able to drop it. If anyone is connected to the tablespace, you will not be able to drop it. If this is not the only temp tablespace, and noone is connected to it, then it will work and is safe.

Answer (score 2):

Ok here we go [oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/physical.htm#BJEIBHJG)

A tablespace in an Oracle database consists of one or more physical datafiles. A datafile can be associated with only one tablespace and only one database.